# I need this regex to use in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

This regex is working fine with `C#` but giving me error in `JavaScript`:

```
(?<=[A-Za-z])[^A-Za-z]+(?=[A-Za-z])
```

Can anyone help me to convert it to `JavaScript`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You're using a "lookbehind" `?<=` which is not supported by javascript.

You'll have to modify the regex to work witout this part.

It would be easier to suggest the newer regex if you share the string that you want it to match.

Answer (score 0):

modify the regex to work lookbehind is not supported by js:

```
     /^ A-Za-z' A-Za-z-' + A-Za-z' $/
```